# prime number checker with prime dividers

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a code that finds prime numbers on VBA , first, it checks all the numbers on column A and prints all its dividers (not including the 1, the number itself)
if the checked number was found prime, it highlights it in red.
now my teacher told me to alter it so only the prime dividers will shown for each num from column A .. I'm pretty much stuck here so any help will be blessed

[image]
this is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer, divisors As Integer, number As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, q As Integer



For i = 2 To Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
 number = Cells(i, 1).Value
 divisors = 0
 k = 3
  
  
    For j = 1 To number
     q = number Mod j
        If q = 0 Then
         divisors = divisors + 1
          If j <> 1 And j <> number Then
          Cells(i, k) = j
           k = k + 1
          End If
        End If
    Next j
            If divisors = 2 Then
             Cells(i, 2).Value = "This is a prime number"
              Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = vbRed
             
            Else
             Cells(i, 2).Value = "Divisors of " & Cells(i, 1).Value
            End If
              Columns("B").AutoFit
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Structurally, your program should have a separate function `IsPrime` that checks primality independant of any other data. Then you would have a function `Factors` that creates a list of factors. You could then create a function `PrimeFactors` by checking primality of each factor. You might want to double-check though, did your teacher ask for Prime Factors or a Prime Factorization? Those are two very different things.

Comment: Generally, when checking primality, you only need to check for factors up to the square root of the number. So for a number like 25, you only need to check `1 2 3 4 5`. This is because any number larger than the square root will be the paired factor to a number less than the square root. For example, the number 36 has a factor 12 because `12*3=36`. But if you were starting from 1, you would have found 3 before you found 12.

Comment: she meant prime factors but i need to use the exciting code that I wrote and alter it

Comment: I'm hesitant to post code to answer your question because it would be Academic Dishonesty for you to use my code for your project. But I am not sure how otherwise to show you a good example of how to achieve your desired output.

Comment: Thank anyway ,I managed to fix it , I added another for loop and another integer .. but I'd be happy to see what was your idea if you'd like to write it down

Comment: If you managed to fix it, it would be possible to self-answer your question thus showing other users what you have done. This would increase the chance for further replies. @Shtritz